# If the order of g is a prime number, is Pollard-rho the best?

Tags: discrete-logarithm

If the bit size is 128 bits, I know that BSGS is not possible due to memory issues.

I know that the complexity of Pollard-rho for 128 bits is 2^64.

and I know that it is not possible to do 2 ^ 64 operations on a typical computer.

Is there any other way? do solve 128bit ECDLP when ord(G)=prime number

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Pollard-rho is the best algorithm known for solving hard instances of ECDLP (those where the generator is of prime order).

The current (public) record seems to be order $2^{117.35}$ for sect113r2 by Daniel J. Bernstein, Susanne Engels, Tanja Lange, Ruben Niederhagen, Christof Paar,  Peter Schwabe and Ralf Zimmermann in [*Faster elliptic-curve discrete logarithms on FPGAs*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/382.pdf) ([eprint, 2016](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/382)). Notice that this is for a curve over a binary field, and prime fields are noticeably harder at equal size (because [cary-less arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-less_product) is cheaper).